# Display category tree of a post in search results

Tags: categories, search

Do anyone know how to display a category tree of a post in the search result.

Foe example: If a post is in level 3 category  level 1-> level 2 -> level 3 where the level one is the parent one.

Comment: Do you mean to ask that how to show category title and description in place of post title under that category in search result??

Answer (score 1):

**i am missing some details but here is the code for this string

"category level 1-> level 2 -> level3"...**

i also included the search term as the title and the loop around it..

```
<h1><?php echo 'Search Results For:'. get_search_query(); ?></h1>
<ul>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    $catName = $category[0]->cat_name;
    $catFatherID = $category[0]->category_parent;
    $catFather = get_the_category_by_ID($catFatherID)
    ?>
    <li class="result"><?php if($catFather){echo $catFather.'&raquo;';}; echo $catName.'&raquo;';the_title(); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

.

Hope This Helps ;)
Cheers, Sagive.

Comment: Nice but what about more then one level up and showing all posts in one tree instead of a tree for each post?

Comment: i dont think thats what he ask - or did i missunderstood? trying to give him to most easy to use easy to change code..